# Blender viewport and UI lag when external monitor connected

Tags: 3d-view, performance

I have a macbook pro running windows 7 and I use a 1080p monitor when at home with laptop screen disabled. When I have my second monitor plugged in (via mini display port -> VGA apple adaptor) there is a lot of UI lag.

Nvidia 650M GT oc'd

i7 quad core hyper threaded 2.7 -> 3.6GHz

8 GB RAM

Answer (score 2):

Turbo boost (3,6GHz) only boosts one core. The others sleep, I guess.
So I guess you shouldn't use the boost here. RAM is okay, unless rendering, graphics card isn't used anyway. I use mini-display-port on my System as well, no problem. But im on windows so maybe it's a MAC's problem. Please check out other programs, like Video editing Programs or other comples ones like photoshop. (there are free trials)

Comment: Photoshop runs fine, vegas runs fine, afert effects runs fine. Are you sure turbo boost only boosts one core? Because I remeber looking at all my cores through a diagnostoc tool (cant remember which but it was probably CPUZ) and seeing all the cores increase in clock. RAM has been fine for rendering, only problems are when I want to run huge fluid sims.I am on windows 7 and belnder is 64bit btw.

Comment: pretty sure...
check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost
There is a table with some caclulations. Seems you 'can' boost more than one core, but only moderate. so 3,6GHz boost would be only 1 (my guess)

(I only read "macbook" so I thought you were running Blender on Mac Os.. But you already mentioned windows in the 1st post, so.. my bad.)

wild guess: search in your bios for "HPET" and set, if it's there, to 64bits.
(double-check if you are using Blender in 64bit edition)

Comment: I have no BIOS, it's a mac remember. Blender is definitely 64 bit, shows up without the 32bit indicator in task manager. May I ask what HPET actually means?

Comment: HPET : High Precision Event Timer. Some Nvidia cards seem to lagg without this.
sorry, of course no bios. it's EFI on mac then.